White noise on Ubuntu screen when I move the mouse
I have a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 install on my Dell XPS15 laptop and am getting a ton of white noise on my screen (see photo). My best guess is that it is related to how the GPU drivers are installed.

Under Software & Updates, in Additional Drivers, I selected Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary) and applied changes. The nvidia-smi command suggests that the driver is installed properly.
I ran the sudo prime-select nvidia command, and prime-select query returns nvidia.
Do I need to change the settings under nvidia-settings?
